# Height adjustments in Flex NavigatorContent

Tags: apache-flex, runtime, height, adjustment

How is it possible to (automatically) adjust the height of a Flex (4) application at runtime so that only the HTML-page scroll bar is shown, not any Flex scroll bar?

I'm using a ViewStack control which will change always its content. So every time some new content (NavigatorContent controls) is shown (which apparently will have different heights) i want the application height to adjust its height in a way it is reflected in changing only the height of the HTML-page.

I have the slight feeling that this means changing the height of the SWF at runtime! Is this true? If yes how to tell the page ? Is this possible?

I hope i explained my problem as close as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://www.unitedmindset.com/jonbcampos/2010/05/18/dynamically-resizing-your-flex-application/) is the solution which worked (for me)!

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already come across a solution to this here's a blog post described a solution for this : http://blog.wezside.co.za/blog/fullscreen-flash-with-browser-scrollbar/

It's a little more then you may be looking for so here's the general gist of it:

1. Set the embedded  swf in the html height to 100%
2. Then on page change in flash, use an ExternalInterface call to set the height of the container div to your flash content.
3. Enjoy browser scrolling for your flash/flex app :P

Comment: Thanks very much, ... no i haven't found a solution yet! I will give this a try and let you know!